# Basic question: $H^1$ and $H^{0,1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

Please could you explain why for a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ (or - if you prefer the analytic world - compact complex manifold) $T$ we have $H^1(\mathcal{O}_T)\simeq H^{0,1}(T)$ as in the bottom of page 13 in this set of notes:

http://www.cgtp.duke.edu/ITP99/morrison/cortona.pdf

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of [Dolbeault's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolbeault_cohomology#Dolbeault.27s_theorem).

(By the way, a compact complex manifold is *not* the same thing as a smooth projective variety. Not all compact complex manifolds are projective.)